# dismissWithClickedButtonIndex not work in toolbar IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

I set a PickView and a `ToolBar` in UIActionSheet The ToolBar has a `UIBarButtonItem` in order to close UIActionSheet, when I click the UIBarButtonItem the `UIActionSheet` should be dismissed
But I founded that When I click the Done Button The UIActionSheet still display in view

```
@IBOutlet weak var _gradeResign: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    _gradeResign.resignFirstResponder()
    self.m_actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, destructiveButtonTitle:nil,otherButtonTitles:"");
    self.m_actionSheet.delegate = self;
    self.m_actionSheet.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/3)
    self.m_actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyle.Default;
    var pickerDataToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.m_actionSheet.frame.width, self.m_actionSheet.frame.height))
    pickerDataToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;
    pickerDataToolbar.sizeToFit();
    var barItmes:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
    var doneBtn:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action:Selector("toolBarDoneClick"))
    barItmes.addObject(doneBtn)
    var flexSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace,target: self, action: nil)
    barItmes.addObject(flexSpace)
    pickerDataToolbar.setItems(barItmes, animated: true)
    m_actionSheet.addSubview(pickerDataToolbar)
    gradePickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 44, self.m_actionSheet.bounds.size.width,self.m_actionSheet.bounds.size.height))
    gradePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true;
    gradePickerView.dataSource = self;
    gradePickerView.delegate = self;
    gradePickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    self.m_actionSheet.addSubview(gradePickerView)
    self.m_actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
    self.m_actionSheet.showFromToolbar(pickerDataToolbar);
    _gradeResign.inputView = self.m_actionSheet;
}

func toolBarDoneClick(){

    self.m_actionSheet.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
}
```

The function `toolBarDoneClick` run current

Comment: Could you describe how you want this to work?  For instance: "when the user clicks on the text field a picker pops up and they select a value it appears in the text field.  When they click Done the picker goes away."

Comment: I'm unclear on the purpose of the action sheet.  Why are you using it?

Comment: hello,@vacawama,This instace is that I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to set up a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` of a `UITextField`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //initialization constants
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    let textField = UITextField()
    var activeTextField:UITextField?
    let pickerData = ["apple","pear","banana"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //pickerview tool bar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44))
        var items = [AnyObject]()
        //making done button
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "donePressed")
        items.append(doneButton)
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

        //creating textfields with a pickerview
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 216)

        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        textField.inputView = pickerView
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 55, 100, 35)
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        textField.delegate = self

        //adding objs to viewController
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) { // became first responder
        activeTextField = textField
    }

    func donePressed() {
        activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ,I have tried this code,but the problem still exist

Comment: Calling `resignFirstResponder` on the `textField` should make the picker go away.

Comment: Sorry ,I make a misgtake,The problem has been solved ,thank you

Comment: Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer if you feel it solved your problem.